# Traveling with 2 passports (German and US) but with a layover in England

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, dual-nationality

I've read several great posts about traveling with 2 passports, specifically German and US. I'll be leaving Boston for Berlin with a layover in Iceland. In Iceland and Germany I will show my German passport. I know that when I am ready to leave Germany, I need to check in with my US passport and then go through exit customs showing my German passport.

My question is the following:

On my return flight from Munich to Boston, I have a layover in London. Which passport do I show them at customs upon entering? And which passport do I use in exit customs?

Thanks!

Comment: Last time I flew out of the UK (Edinburgh to Dublin) I don't recall any encounter with immigration or customs during departure. But maybe Ireland is special.

Comment: Show exit immigration the same passport you entered with, the same as always. Your passport will be checked for immigration in Munich, not London. There you only transit.

Comment: There's no exit control in the UK.

Answer (score 4):

On your flight from Munich to Boston, it is probably easiest to show your German passport. As a German citizen, you can enter the UK with no formalities due to free movement (certainly for the next month or so, anyway).

In the unlikely event that the UK border officer questions your use of your German passport because of your flight booking, then show them the US one. They understand that many people hold dual passports and will not object.

I hold two passports and occasionally have to specifically show one or the other depending on what questions the immigration officers ask.